# How to get the most uniform partition results?

Tags: hadoop, partitioning, partition, data-partitioning, hadoop-partitioning

I don't know if there is any algrithom to get the optimal parition for a key based data partition (need to ensure the same key records in the same result data set).

For example: I have a data set needs to be divided into two parts：

```
key  num_of_records
k1 20
k2 15
k3 2
k4 3
k5 5
```

There are 2^5 kinds of differents partitions. such as

```
part1: k1 k3 k4 (total records: 25)
part2: k2 k5 (total records 20)
```

And another partition is :

```
part1: k1 k4 (total records 23)
part2: k2 k3 k5 (total revords 22)
```

The latter partition is better than the former, since it allows the number of records distributed more evenly in two part.

So, I need an algrithm to find the optimal partition.

Can anyone give me some suggestions about this topic? How could I approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Java's default `hashCode()` method is fine for this. Obviously with a sample size of 45 you might get a difference of a few, but at big data scales it's irrelevant and will tend towards an even distribution.

Comment: Although I agree with what you're saying, the question (kind of) implies that the OP is not happy with the default partitioner, so I don't think that recommending that one is a useful answer.

Comment: He _thinks_ he's not happy. That doesn't affect whether my answer is correct or not.

Comment: I guess it's worth adding that blindly applying `hashCode()` to the entire key isn't useful for all scenarios, it's fine for simple text keys such as those provided in the example.

Comment: You have my upvote for your suggestion, although it only holds true if the number of keys is expected to grow with the size of the dataset. What if the keys are continents ?

Comment: yep, I also can sort all the keys by the number of records, and then I can use a greedy strategy to do this. In most case, it will tend towards an even distribution. I would like to know if there was an algorithm to obtain the theoretical optimal solution. Maybe some algorithm for allocation plan, but i am not sure. so ask for help

Comment: @Tim "sorting by the number of records" is out of question if you mean the number of records in the *current* computation; it's a *chicken and egg* problem, so you can only rely on previous results.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some prior knowledge about the expected cardinality for each key (based on historical results or whatever), it is best to stick with a "random" partitioning scheme like the default one (based on object hash codes) -- as indicated in @benwatsondata's answer.

However, if you're working with very small set of keys (like countries, or continents) and huge differences in cardinality between them (let's say you have millions of values for Europe or North America and only thousands for South America), you need to come up with a partitioner based on key "ranking".

As a simple example, you can have a partitioner that simply maps each of your keys to a partition and falls back to the hashcode default for unknown keys. A mapping tuned for 3 reducers would be:

```
Europe -> P1
North America -> P2
Asia -> P3
South America -> P3
Australia -> P2
Africa -> P1
__default__ -> hashCode-based
```

A smarter version of the above would get both the number of reducers and the ranked list as parameters and it will figure out the optimal partitioning scheme itself.